# Need help implementing this state-variable filter

Tags: python, signal-processing

Pursuant to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/86305/how-do-i-use-the-lazzarini-timoney-dsvf-as-a-sine-generator), I rewrote some simple generator code into a Python filter class and tried to get the same result out of the filter itself.  It didn't work.  There is a bunch of code here and I'm not sure where the problem is exactly; it's probably somewhere in `DSVF.filter_sample()`

This python code works, and is based on the Chamberlin DSVF:

```py
from numpy import sin, pi
import numpy as np
import pyaudio as pya
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fft as fft

f0=np.single(440)
fs=np.single(96000)

frq = np.single(2*sin(pi*f0/fs))
a=frq
print(a)

c_sin = np.single(0)
c_cos = np.single(1)

pyAudio = pya.PyAudio()
audioOut = pyAudio.open(format=pya.get_format_from_width(width=2), channels=1, rate=int(fs), output=True)
sin_wave = []
sin_wave_np = []
for i in range(0, np.uint(fs)):

    # Convert to 16-bit scaled output
    # The generated sine wave overflows a bit, so scale it down
    sin_out = np.int16(0.999*(c_sin) * 0.5 * (2**16-1))

    # Iterate based on Chamberlin DSVF with q=0
    c_cos -= a*c_sin
    c_sin += a*c_cos
    # Numpy sine wave for reference
    sin_out_np = (sin(2*pi*i*f0/fs) * 0.5) * (2**16-1)
    
    # Build the arrays of samples
    sin_wave.append(np.int16(sin_out))
    sin_wave_np.append(np.int16(sin_out_np))

# Plot the sine waves one overlayed over the other
for s in [[sin_wave_np, 'red'], [sin_wave, 'blue']]:
    x = range(0, np.uint(f0))
    plt.plot(x, s[0][0:int(f0)], color=s[1])
    audioOut.write(np.array(s[0], dtype='int16').tobytes())
audioOut.stop_stream()
audioOut.close()
pyAudio.terminate()
plt.show()

# Concatenate both and run an FFT to ensure only f0 and -f0 show up
twosec = np.concatenate((sin_wave_np, sin_wave))
yf = fft.fft(twosec)
xf = [x / f0 for x in fft.fftfreq(np.uint(fs)*2,1/fs)]
plt.plot(xf, np.abs(yf))
plt.show()
```

This is my filter code attempting to replicate the same result, which I am having no luck figuring out what I did wrong.  It implements both filter modes, but I'm only using the Chamberlin mode to test.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import sin, tan, pi
from typing import Optional
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fft as fft

class FilterModes:
    DSVF_CHAMBERLIN = 'Chamberlin'
    DSVF_LAZZARINI_TIMONEY = 'Lazzarini-Timoney'

class DSVF:
    def __init__(self,
                 sample_rate: int = 48000,
                 Q: float = np.sqrt(2),
                 frequency: float = 440,
                 bandpass_z1: float = 0,
                 lowpass_z1: float = 0,
                 mode: str = FilterModes.DSVF_CHAMBERLIN):
        self._mode = mode
        self._fs = sample_rate
        self.set_state(Q=Q,
                       q = None,
                   frequency=frequency,
                   bandpass_z1=bandpass_z1,
                   lowpass_z1=lowpass_z1,
                   highpass=0,
                   lowpass=0,
                   bandpass=0)
    
    def _get_f(self, frequency: float):
        f = None
        match self._mode:
            case FilterModes.DSVF_LAZZARINI_TIMONEY:
                f = np.tan(pi * frequency / self._fs)
            case _:
                f = 2 *np.sin(pi * frequency / self._fs)
        return f
    
    def filter_sample(self, sample: Optional[float] = 0):
        # Need the last cycle's z^-1
        lowpass_z1 = None
        match self._mode:
            case FilterModes.DSVF_LAZZARINI_TIMONEY:
                lowpass_z1 = self._lowpass + self._f * self._bandpass
            case _:
                lowpass_z1 = self._lowpass
        ##############################
        ## Generate Highpass output ##
        ##############################
        # FIXME:  Check that proper lowpass feedback is being used.
        highpass = sample + self._bandpass_z1 * -self._q
        match self._mode:
            case FilterModes.DSVF_LAZZARINI_TIMONEY:
                highpass -= self._lowpass_z1
            case _:
                highpass -= self._lowpass
        
        ##############################
        ## Generate Bandpass Output ##
        ##############################
        f_highpass = highpass * self._f
        bandpass = self._bandpass_z1 + f_highpass
        bandpass_z1 = bandpass
        f_bandpass = None
        match self._mode:
            case FilterModes.DSVF_LAZZARINI_TIMONEY:
                bandpass_z1 = bandpass_z1 + f_highpass
                f_bandpass = bandpass * self._f
            case _:
                f_bandpass = self._bandpass_z1 * self._f
        
        #############################
        ## Generate Lowpass Output ##
        #############################
        lowpass = f_bandpass + self._lowpass_z1
        # Replace state
        self._highpass = highpass
        self._bandpass = bandpass
        self._bandpass_z1 = bandpass_z1
        self._lowpass = lowpass
        self._lowpass_z1 = lowpass_z1
    
    def get_state(self):
        return { 'Lowpass':  self._lowpass,
                 'Bandpass': self._bandpass,
                 'Highpass': self._highpass,
                 'Bandpass z1': self._bandpass_z1,
                 'Lowpass z1': self._lowpass_z1
               }

    def set_state(self,
                   Q: Optional[float] = None,
                   q: Optional[float] = None,
                   frequency: Optional[float] = None,
                   bandpass_z1: Optional[float] = None,
                   lowpass_z1: Optional[float] = None,
                   highpass: Optional[float] = None,
                   bandpass: Optional[float] = None,
                   lowpass: Optional[float] = None):
        if Q is not None: self._q = 1 / Q
        if q is not None: self._q = q
        if frequency is not None: self._f = self._get_f(frequency)
        if bandpass_z1 is not None: self._bandpass_z1 = bandpass_z1
        if lowpass_z1 is not None: self._lowpass_z1 = lowpass_z1
        if highpass is not None: self._highpass = highpass
        if bandpass is not None: self._bandpass = bandpass
        if lowpass is not None: self._lowpass = lowpass

dsvFilter = DSVF(bandpass_z1 = 1, lowpass_z1 = 0)
dsvFilter.set_state(q=0)

fs=int(48000)
sin_wave = np.array([],dtype='int16')
for i in range(0,fs):
    dsvFilter.filter_sample()
    s = dsvFilter.get_state()
    s16 = np.int16(0.999*(np.single(s['Lowpass z1'])) * 0.5 * (2**16-1))
    sin_wave = np.append(sin_wave, [s16])

plt.plot(range(0, np.uint(fs)), sin_wave)
plt.show()
```

It's giving me a warning as well, which I haven't been able to understand or resolve:

```
dsvf.py:117: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
s16 = np.int16(0.999*(np.single(s['Lowpass z1'])) * 0.5 * (2**16-1))
```

What'd I do wrong and why is it wrong?

Comment: Have you tried stripping out all the mode-checking stuff and making a straight Chamberlin-filter class? That seems like a good first step, if your first code, which isn't organized into a class, works as expected. (Disclaimer: I know nothing about the audio subject matter.)

Comment: Nope. I tried stepping through it in Thonny, which annoyingly isn't allowing me to inspect objects during debugging, to verify the execution path, but haven't outright carved the code out. I'm going to take a break and see if I can find it by mapping the original back to the filter itself and tracing the same path in my filter class, but help is always helpful.

Comment: Compute the value that you're passing to np.int16 and check if it can be represented as a 16 bit integer.

Comment: To clarify, is int16 just supposed to convert the number to an integer or are you intentionally doing a modulo 65536 operation into a -32k to +32k range? I don't know the technical details of your field, but that's what the warning is for. If that's the issue I can do a better answer write-up tomorrow.

Comment: Ah, that tells me something. It's getting invalid value because the oscillator is unstable and the amplitude is growing out of control (it's supposed to be a sine wave…).  int16 is just to convert the floating-point value to a 16 bit integer; the valid range is -1 to 1 and I map that onto a 16-bit integer range.  I've done some rewrite to test this as a filter and while it follows the diagram, it's NOT giving me correct results…at all.  I really should have posted this on the dsp stackexchange I think.

Comment: Should be moved to dsp.stackexchange.com; I wasn't sure where to put it, so I put it on programming. (Can't select that site on the "belongs on another site" option.) This seems inappropriate: the code implements a concept deeply specific to a certain field and people responding have pointed out they are unfamiliar with the underlying subject matter.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to calculate lowpass first on each iteration, instead of calculating highpass using the last lowpass value.  This adds in the z^-1 (basically doubles it I think?).